Stabilizer states entanglement entropy
I am trying to calculate the entanglement entropy of N qubits of stabilizer states. I have seen the following QCSE post: Measuring entanglement entropy using a stabilizer circuit simulator, where it states that

According to this paper, the
entanglement entropy for a state is: $$S = |A| - log_2|\mathcal{S}_A|\,,$$
with $|A|$ being the size of the bipartition and $|\mathcal{S}_A|$ is
the part of the stabilizers of the state that acts on $\bar{A}$ with
an identity.

However, I don't want to use this equation and I wanted to see if there exists any function or way to calculate the entropy being given the stabilizers of a state.
For example, this is a code in qiskit for the Bell state:
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
stabilizer = StabilizerState(qc)
statevector = Statevector.from_instruction(qc)
entropy_value = entropy(partial_trace(statevector, [1]), base=2)

But it does not use the stabilizer, and when I generalize and increase N, the entropy function, which calculates the entropy from the state by diagonalizing the density matrix, won't work. (the eigenvalues don't converge.)
